# Show all records using INNER JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql

I am familiar with `INNER JOIN` just enough to understand the basics. But is there a way that I can select all records from both tables without cluttering the SQL sting with each column name. I was thinking in the line with the below code

```
SELECT * FROM new_case
INNER JOIN dispatch
ON new_case.file_nr = dispatch.case_nr
WHERE new_case.id = '27'
```

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, and an explanation of what *you* mean by "cluttering the SQL string with the column names".

Comment: Edited to remove PHP tag, question has nothing to do with PHP

Comment: I have edited the question, there is one common column I need to join on but i want to echo all the information from the different tables without placing each database and table in the string, there is over 50 columns in each table so the string will be very long if I have to mention each one

Comment: As long as you don't have overlapping column names `SELECT *` will work fine. If you do have overlapping column names you will need to use column aliases for each one to ensure you get all the data in the output.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Results from both tables:

`SELECT nc.*, d.* 
 FROM new_case nc 
  INNER JOIN dispatch d 
  ON nc.file_nr = d.case_nr 
 WHERE nc.id = '27'`

Comment: Great this worked for me, just to confirm the nc and d is aliases set for the table names if I am correct?

Answer (score 1):

This is what i'd try;

```
SELECT ft.*, af.* FROM new_case ft INNER JOIN dispatch af ON (ft.file_nr = af.case_nr) WHERE new_case.id = '27'
```